# how do i format curlly bracket data in php

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

i have this type of data store in mysql, how can i echo only the amount value from this?

`{"1":{"amount":"700","date":"2022-10-31","amount_discount":"0","amount_fine":"0","description":"","collected_by":"John Doe","payment_mode":"Cash","received_by":"12","inv_no":1},"2":{"amount":"300","date":"2022-12-17","description":" Paid by: Jane Doe","amount_discount":0,"amount_fine":"0","payment_mode":"upi","received_by":"23","inv_no":2}}`

this code looks like json data, if yes then should i be using jquery to echo the values or is there a way to do it in php?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use the json_decode function to turn it into a PHP object and then access its properties. For your example, you can do this to get the "amount" property:

```
<?php
$js='{"1":{"amount":"700","date":"2022-10-31","amount_discount":"0","amount_fine":"0","description":"","collected_by":"John Doe","payment_mode":"Cash","received_by":"12","inv_no":1},"2":{"amount":"300","date":"2022-12-17","description":" Paid by: Jane Doe","amount_discount":0,"amount_fine":"0","payment_mode":"upi","received_by":"23","inv_no":2}}';
echo json_decode($js)->{"1"}->amount;
?>
```

Comment: is there a way to get all the values of amounts {"1"} {"2"} {"3"} etc

Comment: @user3647738 json_decode($js) make JSON to an array, so you can access all items

Comment: Actually this is what i was trying to do and it worked


$json_string   = '{"1":{"amount":"700","date":"2022-10-31","amount_discount":"0","amount_fine":"0","description":"","collected_by":"John Doe","payment_mode":"Cash","received_by":"12","inv_no":1},"2":{"amount":"300","date":"2022-12-17","description":" Paid by: Jane Doe","amount_discount":0,"amount_fine":"0","payment_mode":"upi","received_by":"23","inv_no":2}};

$data = json_decode($json_string, TRUE);


$total = 0;
foreach ($data as $value) {
    $total += $value['amount'];
 
}
echo $total;

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = json_decode('{"1":{"amount":"700","date":"2022-10-31","amount_discount":"0","amount_fine":"0","description":"","collected_by":"John Doe","payment_mode":"Cash","received_by":"12","inv_no":1},"2":{"amount":"300","date":"2022-12-17","description":" Paid by: Jane Doe","amount_discount":0,"amount_fine":"0","payment_mode":"upi","received_by":"23","inv_no":2}}');
Ex1: ((array) $data)[1]->amount
Ex2: $data->{'1'}->amount]);
```